# Why is my openfile.php not working properly in Safari or IE?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins, content-disposition

I have a very simple file called openfile.php that sets a content-disposition and forces a browser to download a specified file.

It works fine in FF, but in Safari, it downloads a strange .xhtml file that on closer examination, appears to be the default error page that would occur.

In IE, you are just directed to this error page.

Can anyone deduce what is going on here?

Here is a link : http://hqinternetsolutions.com/Websites/Fabric%20Traditions/?page_id=215

**This is the code that opens the file**

```
<?php
if ( ! isset($_GET['file']) )
    die();

if ( strpos( $_GET['file'], (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https|' : 'http|') . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ) === false )
    die();

require_once('../lib/class.mimetype.php');
$mime = new mimetype();

$fPath = str_replace('http|', 'http://', $_GET['file']);
$fPath = str_replace('https|', 'https://', $fPath);
$fType = $mime->getType( $fPath );
$fName = basename($fPath);

$origname = preg_replace('/_#_#\d*/','',$fName);

$fContent = fetch_content( $fPath );

output_content( $fContent, $origname );

function fetch_content( $url ) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );

    ob_start();

    curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $fContent = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    return $fContent;
}

function output_content( $content, $name ) {
    header( "Expires: Wed, 9 Nov 1983 05:00:00 GMT" );
    header( "Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT" );
    header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $name );
    header( "Content-type: application/octet-stream" );
    header( "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" );

    echo $content;
}
?>
```

Comment: Appears to be working in IE9.

Answer (score 1):

Your header is

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Pillow1.pdf
```

but it should be

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Pillow1.pdf"
```

Not sure if this is the problem, as I don't use windows.

Comment: How did you view those headers? I'm using mac as well and having this problem in Safari..

Comment: Don't know if cURL is available for mac, but should be. curl -i gives you the headers. To make it clear: I am using Ubuntu Lucid

Comment: For capturing packets you may also use Wireshark. It will capture for you all network communication where you can filter the HTTP and check for exact HTTP request and response from server.

Comment: The first variant is valid as well.

Answer (score 0):

The link doesn't work for me even in Firefox, the content that get's downloaded is some HTML page.

Looking at the headers you are sending (http://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhqinternetsolutions.com%2FWebsites%2FFabric%2520Traditions%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fwp-publication-archive%2Fincludes%2Fopenfile.php%3Ffile%3Dhttp|hqinternetsolutions.com%2FWebsites%2FFabric%2520Traditions%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2011%2F12%2FPillow1.pdf) I note:

- the Expires header is broken
- there is no Content-Transfer-Encoding in HTTP
- Content-Type should be the type for PDF

(but none of these explain why the wrong content is sent)

Answer (score 0):

The reason this PHP will not work is because of the `%20` in the URL. You can't have spaces or it causes the delimiter finder in the script to fail.